# Substitute multiple substrings in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match Strings that look like this in Perl

```
%TRMMHDT128F422F115<SEP>SOJEZBM12A6D4FEA96<SEP>Thursday<SEP>A Hole In The World (Album Version) [etc]
```

The strings will not always have the parentheses and/or brackets at the end. What I want to do is remove all the fluff around the song, and eventually all the punctuation in the song. I can do this currently in two passes with these statements:

```
$line =~ s/.*>//;
$line =~ s/(\(.*)|(\[.*)//;
```

I would like to do this all at once, but if I add a pipe `|` after the first expression and before the second it will not remove anything in the parentheses or brackets. Like so:

```
$line =~ s/.*>|(\(.*)|(\[.*)//;
```

Now in a regex tester this matches everything I would like it to match but it isn't substituting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Substitute multiple substrings in Perl:**

```
$line =~ s/.*>|(\(.*)|(\[.*)//g;
```

In a Perl regex, the `g` modifier continually applies the RegEx until it stops matching.

Though as the last two conditions are nearly identical, I'd probably consolidate it to:

```
$line =~ s/.*>|([([].*)//g;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand how to do the rest of the punctuation as well now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$line =~ s/(.*>)(.*)(\(.*)/$2/;
```

What this does is that it matches the entire line for that pattern, and substitutes the entire line with $2 which is the song title.

Comment: Closer to OP's intent may be: `$line =~ s/(.*>)(.*)([([].*)/$2/;`